# Retrieving Skype chat messages in android

Tags: android, skype

I want to develop a third party application which retrieves all the chat messages from the skype application which is pre-installed in my device.

Comment: not possible. They are stored in encrypted databases.

Comment: Right, it's not like text message or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for telling this story. Next time when you post a question, ask an actual question